# Sending Image from client to server over the network using socket programming are getting corrupted at server side

Tags: python, mininet

My task is to send some images over the network to other machine using python socket programming. But doing this results in a corrupted image at server side. I cannot understand why my images are getting corrupted on receiving at server machine. Below is my code that I tried in two different machines.

I tried different encoding techniques like base64, utf8 etc but could not get the desired results

### Server Code

```
import socket
import sys
import traceback
from threading import Thread
import base64

def main():
    start_server()

def start_server():
    host = "172.16.15.52"
    port = 8220        # arbitrary non-privileged port
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)   # SO_REUSEADDR flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in TIME_WAIT state, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire
    print("Socket created")

    try:
        soc.bind((host, port))
    except:
        print("Bind failed. Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit()
    soc.listen(5)       # queue up to 5 requests
    print("Socket now listening")
    # infinite loop- do not reset for every requests
    while True:
        connection, address = soc.accept()
        ip, port = str(address[0]), str(address[1])
        print("Connected with " + ip + ":" + port)

        try:
            Thread(target=client_thread, args=(connection, ip, port)).start()
        except:
            print("Thread did not start.")
            traceback.print_exc()

    soc.close()

def client_thread(connection, ip, port, max_buffer_size = 64000):
    is_active = True

    while is_active:
        client_input = receive_input(connection, max_buffer_size)

        if "--quit--" in client_input:
            connection.close()
            is_active = False
        else:
            connection.sendall("-".encode("utf8"))

def receive_input(connection, max_buffer_size):
    client_input = connection.recv(max_buffer_size)
    imageData = client_input
    fh = open("result_img/imageToSave.png","wb")
    fh.write(imageData.decode('base64'))
    fh.close()
    client_input_size = sys.getsizeof(client_input)

    if client_input_size > max_buffer_size:
        print("The input size is greater than expected {}".format(client_input_size))

    decoded_input = client_input.decode("utf8").rstrip()  # decode and strip end of line
    result = process_input(decoded_input)

    return result

def process_input(input_str):

    return str(input_str)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Client Code

```
import socket
import sys
import random
from time import time
import os
import base64

def main():
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "172.16.15.52"
    port = 8220

    try:
        soc.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print("Connection error")
        sys.exit()
    
    fileNames = os.listdir('record/result_img/')
    for i in fileNames:
    with open('record/result_img/'+i, "rb") as imageFile:
        str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        if len(str) <= 62000:   # size of the image should be less than 64kb due to limitation of TCP packets
                message = str
        soc.sendall(message)
        if soc.recv(64000).decode("utf8") == "-":
            pass        # null operation
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The expected results is the image at client side should be received similar on server side

Comment: More details on the error you're seeing would be useful

Comment: So, what is the difference between the sent image and the received image?

Comment: The image that is received at the server machine is marked as corrupted. When I open the image, Image Viewer says the file is corrupted. On the other hand if I run both client code and server code on the same machine then it is working correctly but running client code on one machine and server code on other machine gives me this error. I am unable to understand why this happening. By the way I am Using Ubuntu 16.04 server edition for your reference.